# Exponential based Curve-Fit using Math.Net

Tags: c#, matlab, curve-fitting, mathnet-numerics

I'm very new to the Math.Net Library and I'm having problems trying to do curve-fitting based on an exponential function. More specifically I intend to use this function:

```
f(x) = a*exp(b*x) + c*exp(d*x)
```

Using MATLAB I get pretty good results, as shown in the following image:

[image: blah]

MATLAB calculates the following parameters:

```
f(x) = a*exp(b*x) + c*exp(d*x)
Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
a =   29.6       ( 29.49     , 29.71)
b =    0.000408  (  0.0003838,  0.0004322)
c =   -6.634     ( -6.747    , -6.521)
d =   -0.03818   ( -0.03968  , -0.03667)
```

Is it possible to achieve these results using Math.Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it appears there is not exponential support at this time.  However there's a discussion on Math.NET forums where a maintainer proposes a workaround:

https://discuss.mathdotnet.com/t/exponential-fit/131

Contents duplicated in case link gets broken:

> You can, by transforming it, similar to Linearizing non-linear models
>   by transformation. Something along the lines of the following should
>   work:

```
double[] Exponential(double[] x, double[] y,
    DirectRegressionMethod method = DirectRegressionMethod.QR)
{
    double[] y_hat = Generate.Map(y, Math.Log);
    double[] p_hat = Fit.LinearCombination(x, y_hat, method, t => 1.0, t => t);
    return new[] {Math.Exp(p_hat[0]), p_hat[1]}; 
}
```

> Example usage:

```
double[] x = new[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
double[] y = new[] { 2.0, 4.1, 7.9 };
double[] p = Exponential(x,y); // a=1.017, r=0.687
double[] yh = Generate.Map(x,k => p[0]*Math.Exp(p[1]*k)) // 2.02, 4.02, 7.98
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at Math.net, it seems that Math.net does various types of regression, whereas your function require some type of iterative method. For instance Gauss-Newton's method where you would use linear regression in each iteration to solve a (overdetermined) system of linear equations, but this would still require some "manual" work with writing the method.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is: not yet, I believe. Basically, there is contribution of whole `csmpfit` package, but it yet to be integrated into Math.Net. You could use it as separate library and then after full integration move to Math.Net. Link http://csmpfit.codeplex.com